Fabric JS custom class not recognized with v6 upgraded
I upgraded the fabric js version to v6+, and create class method was removed in this new version. Changed my code as follows to work with new fabric version:
import * as fabric from "fabric";
import { QRCodeSVG } from "qrcode.react";

import { FabricObjectMetadataOptions } from "../common/interfaces";
import { convertJSXToXMLString } from "../utils";

export class QrCodeObject extends fabric.Group {
  static type = "Qrcode";
  private element: fabric.FabricObject;

  constructor(options: QrCodeObjectProps) {
    super([], {
      ...options,
      lockRotation: true,
      lockSkewingX: true,
      lockSkewingY: true,
    });

    this.element = {} as fabric.FabricObject;
    this.initialize(options);
    return this;
  }

  private async initialize(options: QrCodeObjectProps) {
    const svgString = QrCodeObject.toSVGString(options);
    this.element = await this.createSVGFromString(svgString, options);
    this.add(this.element);
    this.lockMiddleControls();
  }

  private createSVGFromString(
    svgString: string,
    options: QrCodeObjectProps
  ): Promise<fabric.FabricObject> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString).then((resultSVG) => {
        const obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(
          resultSVG.objects as fabric.FabricObject[],
          resultSVG.options
        );
        obj.set({
          metadata: options.metadata,
        });
        resolve(obj);
      });
    });
  }

  static toSVGString({
    content,
    widthContainer,
    level = "L",
    bgColor = "#ffffff",
    fgColor = "#000000",
  }: QrCodeReactProps) {
    const svg = QRCodeSVG({
      value: content,
      size: widthContainer,
      level,
      bgColor,
      fgColor,
    });

    const xmlString = convertJSXToXMLString(svg);
    return xmlString;
  }

  private lockMiddleControls() {
    this.setControlsVisibility({
      mt: false,
      mb: false,
      ml: false,
      mr: false,
      bl: true,
      br: true,
      tl: true,
      tr: true,
      mtr: false,
    });
  }

  toJSON() {
    return super.toObject();
  }
}

export interface QrCodeReactProps {
  content: string;
  widthContainer: number;
  bgColor?: string;
  fgColor?: string;
  level?: "L" | "M" | "Q" | "H";
  includeMargin?: boolean;
  imageSettings?: {
    src: string;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
    excavate?: boolean;
  };
}

export interface QrCodeObjectProps
  extends QrCodeReactProps,
    Partial<fabric.FabricObjectProps> {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  metadata: FabricObjectMetadataOptions;
  content: string;
  widthContainer: number;
}

declare module "fabric" {
  namespace fabric {
    class Qrcode extends QrCodeObject {
      constructor(element: any, options: any);
    }
  }
}

The code is working fine, the custom component renders and after I save it with canvas.ToJson() method, but when restore canvas data with the loadFromJSON function, I get the the following error:

Fabric: No class registered for Qrcode

So far I have not found a way to fix this error.
const handlers = {
    save: () => {
      saveData(canvas?.toJSON());
    },
    restore: (jsonData: string) => canvas?.loadFromJSON(jsonData, () => {
          canvas?.renderAll();
        });
  };


fabric.classRegistry.setClass(QrCodeObject)

Documentation (empty)
